# How to classify a dataset into 5 classes even though the performance is low?

Tags: machine-learning, classification, feature-selection, supervised-learning

I have a dataset of 5 classes with 8 features, say A, B, C, D and E. Now when I try to classify these into individual classes, I get accuracy, specificity and sensitivity of approx 50-60%, which is not a good rate. Now since I made the dataset myself, I know that classes [A,B,C,D] can be categorized into 1 class and [E] into another. Once a sample has been predicted to be in class [A,B,C,D], I can again break the class distribution to [A,B,C] and [D]. Once a sample has been predicted to be in class [A,B,C], I can again break the class distribution to 3 final classes [A],[B] and [C]. I pass my dataset by combining multiple classes into one as mentioned above to get the output. In the first stage of classification I get to know whether a sample is class E or not, in the second I get to know whether the sample (if not belonging to E) belongs to D or not. In the third I get to know whether a sample which is not E and D belongs to A or B or C.

Is this method of pipelining viable and a logical solution?